# Are libSystem.B.dylib and/or the -all_load flag required for the version 1.1.3 of Urban Airship?

Tags: iphone, ios, urbanairship.com

I am using Urban Airship to send push notifications to users of an iPhone app.

I am using:

- Xcode 4.2.1
- iOS 5 SDK
- libUAirship 1.1.3
- targetting iOS 4.3 & above

Questions

1. Is "weak" linking (i.e. marking as optional) against libSystem.B.dylib (still) required? I was hoping it wasn't because it doesn't work with the iOS Simulator.
2. Is the "all_load" Other Linker Flag required?

I am NOT using either of these (because it looked like they were removed from the instructions when I recently updated to libUAirship 1.1.3).

I am seeing several iPhone 4S's with iOS 5.0.1 crashing with SIGSEGV (SEGV_ACCERR):

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib 0x315d0fbc objc_msgSend + 15
1    Schools 0x00054d5f -[UA_ASIHTTPRequest handleStreamError] (UA_ASIHTTPRequest.m:3656)
2    Schools 0x0005518b -[UA_ASIHTTPRequest scheduleReadStream] (UA_ASIHTTPRequest.m:3713)
3    Foundation 0x31a21943 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 414
4    CoreFoundation 0x37ac4a63 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
5    CoreFoundation 0x37ac46c9 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 364
6    CoreFoundation 0x37ac329f __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
7    CoreFoundation 0x37a464dd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
8    CoreFoundation 0x37a463a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
9    GraphicsServices 0x375c4fcd GSEventRunModal + 156
10   UIKit 0x34ed6743 UIApplicationMain + 1090
11   Schools 0x0002686f -[NotificationsViewController tappedModelRowAtIndexPath:] (NotificationsViewController.m:195)
```

**Is the crash related to the library or linker flag? Or any ideas on what's going on?**

Comment: it doesn't look like it's #1, since that should hit you right away at launch if it was a problem. as for #2, i would guess it isn't causing the crash either. do you know what the user is doing when it crashes? i.e. is it on startup or does it happen some time into using the app.

Comment: Runtime crashes are, btw, unrelated to linking. If a symbol can't be found due to a missing library, it won't even link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this in the [CHANGELOG for urbanairship / ios-library](https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library/blob/master/CHANGELOG):

- Removed the need for extra linker flags (all_load and the weak ref to libSystem.B)

Comment: I would love to know why this is crashing. It looked like some work was done on UA_ASIHTTPRequest recently (problems with ASIHTTPRequest). I don't use the latter, but I have Crittercism (3.0.7rc) & they might.